# Can I specify VM names while creating a cluster in Google Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

When I create Kubernates cluster in my Google cloud, it builds VMs with autogenerated names like `k8s-cluster-xyz123`. Is it possible to specify custom names for them?

Also, how do I add a tag to it's instance group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the names as these are managed by the instance group managing the nodes. You can apply tags with the [--tags option](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create#--tags).

Comment: I found workaround for renaming a VM by cloning it. Any idea is it safe to do it for cluster node?

Comment: You should not do that since you will break autoscaling and upgrades. Cloning a VM will boot it up with the right configuration to join the GKE cluster and talk to the master, but all the upgrading / autoscaling facilities will be unaware of the node.